# "Do you know what IS the best thing" or "Do you know what the best thing IS"

Tags: word-order, questions

Which one is correct?

> 1. Do you know what is the best thing that's ever happened to me?
> 2. Do you know what the best thing that's ever happened to me is?

And also, how can I know when the word "is" goes at the end of a sentence or not? Because I've also seen cases where people write *«I don't know what love is»*

Comment: Both would be understood to be asking the same thing, but the second one feels more "correct" and natural (aside from the missing "know").

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical. The normal rules about embedded questions lead to 2.

But because the complement *the best thing that's ever happened to me* is long, and the verb *is* is very short, sentences like this can become confusing, especially in writing; so the rule of [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) allows sentence 1.

However, to my ear, the most natural sentence is

> 3. Do you know what the best thing is that's ever happened to me?

which is also allowed by extraposition, and has the advantage that the *is* can be stressed.